# UIBezierPath stroke redraws it multiple times in touchesMoved

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, cgcontext

I am implementing a coloring app in `Swift 3.0` which uses `UIBezierPath` for touch to fill coloring style. In `touchesBegan` I create the path:

```
touchFillPath = UIBezierPath()
```

and in `touchesMoved` I stroke it for each new point:

```
touchFillPath.addLine(to: location)
touchFillPath.stroke()
```

but this results in the path stroked multiple times above the same area, and hence the selected color opacity changes.

I need to stroke the path for each touchesMoved call to allow the user to see the area colored while he is moving touches.

How can I stroke the same path multiple times without overriding the same area multiple times?

Comment: "this results in the path stroked multiple times above the same area, and hence the selected color opacity changes" ... If so, you must be rendering this to an image every `touchesMoved` or something like that. We need more context to answer this question, because the problem isn't the `stroke` of the path, but rather what you're doing with the broader context. But the answer is likely to be either (a) just stroke a new path from the last `location` to the new one each time; or (b) don't build a new image (or whatever). Hard to say without more context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@joeybladb I have tried your solution, but it draws small segments for each 'touchesMoved' action.

So to fix this, I save all points touched in an array:

```
pathPoints.append(NSValue(cgPoint:location))
```

and after calling `touchFillPath.removeAllPoints()`, I add all these points again to the path:

```
for (index, element) in (pathPoints.enumerated())! {
   let point = element.cgPointValue
   if index == 0 {
       touchFillPath.move(to: point)
   } else {
       touchFillPath.addLine(to: point)
   }
}
```

so that the next time I call `touchFillPath.stroke()`, it strokes the whole path:

```
touchFillPath.move(to: lastPoint)
touchFillPath.addLine(to: location)
touchFillPath.stroke()
```

Answer (score 2):

After `touchFillPath.stroke()` you'll need to reset the path:

```
touchFillPath.removeAllPoints()
touchFillPath.move(to: location)
```